# Concatenate all files recursively, ignoring one file extension

Tags: unix

I want to create a concatenated file which appends all files except those which end in .XYZ from a directory (recursing into subdirectories).

I tried this but it does not work:

```
find . -type f | grep -v *.XYZ -exec cat {} \; > /tmp/alldata.txt
```

This works but fails to exclude files ending in ".XYZ":

```
 find . -type f -exec cat {} \; > /tmp/alldata.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -not -name "*.XYZ" -exec cat {} \; > /tmp/alldata.txt
```

More recent versions of `gnu find` include `-not` which negates the next argument. In this case, you can combine that with the `-name` argument to get what you want without invoking `grep -v`.